flutter video player with chiew controller playing dynamic urls
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class LoopingVideoPlayer extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String animationUrl;
  final String? image;
  final bool autoPlay;
  final bool looping;

  const LoopingVideoPlayer({
    required this.animationUrl,
    super.key,
    this.image,
    this.autoPlay = true,
    this.looping = true,
  });

  @override
  LoopingVideoPlayerState createState() => LoopingVideoPlayerState();
}

class LoopingVideoPlayerState extends ConsumerState<LoopingVideoPlayer> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeVideoPlayer();
  }

  void _initializeVideoPlayer() {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(widget.animationUrl),
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
        mixWithOthers: true,
      ),
    );
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture =
        _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
          autoPlay: widget.autoPlay,
          looping: widget.looping,
          showControls: false,
        );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(LoopingVideoPlayer oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.animationUrl != widget.animationUrl) {
      _videoPlayerController.dispose();
      _chewieController?.dispose();
      _initializeVideoPlayer();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            _chewieController != null) {
          _videoPlayerController.setPlaybackSpeed(0.5);
          _videoPlayerController.setVolume(0);
          return Chewie(controller: _chewieController!);
        } else {
          return widget.image != null
              ? CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: widget.image!)
              : const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

that is my code for video player video is playing fine but after changing 2 -3 videos mobile start hanging plus on some time its give error "FlutterError - LateInitializationError: Field '_chewieController@1236520513' has not been initialized"
what can be cause of this any suggestion will be helpfull.

if you move _videoPlayerController initiation to initState (not in _initializeVideoPlayer), is the problem still occurred?

i tried all the scenario but its still causing the issue.
